# my button cannot click

Tags: android, buttonclick

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/li"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:background="@drawable/title_bg">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/invitebackButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/back_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"      />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/invitation_sinatitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/invite_myfriends"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dip"      />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button android:id="@+id/invite_mobile_Button"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp" 
        android:text="@string/invite_my_friends" /> 
    <Button android:id="@+id/clean_Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
        android:layout_margin="2dp" 
        android:text="@string/invite_clean" />

 </LinearLayout>

 <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/mobileinvitelist" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
       android:layout_below="@id/li"    />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

you see in my layout have invite_mobile_Button  and clear_button,but when I run my app,the two button not get focus and click. Can you give me some clue?

Comment: it seems your ExpandableListView is overlaying LinearLayout .

Comment: what u have tried in your code for click event paste it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set  `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

so your ExpandableListView fills in all the window, as Akki comments. That's why your buttons can't be clicked, because the ExpandableListView overlays them.

Try to change it to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` or position the ExpandableListView and the LinearLayout(@+id/buttonLayout) explicitly, i.e., (@+id/buttonLayout) is set below (@+id/li) and the ExpandableListView is set below (@+id/buttonLayout), so the layout could display correctly.